# golang html/template define not working as intended

Tags: go

the `html/template` module has a `define/template` feature that im trying to use to make it easier to change only one file that contains the global base of my website but its not working as intended.

`base.html`:

```html
{{define "base"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
{{template "content"}}
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

`index.html:`

```html
{{template "base"}}

{{define "content"}}
I'm page 1
{{end}}
```

`blog.html:`

```
{{template "base"}}

{{define "content"}}
I'm page 2
{{end}}
```

I expect to get `I'm page 1` when i call index.html and `I'm page 2` when i call blog.html but with both files i get `I'm page 1` as the output. (i don't know what a dot at the end of template does but all combinations of that don't work aswell).

Comment: You cannot redefine and replace templates like that. Do the reverse: define index.html and blog.html as page1 and page2 respectively, import common header.html and footer.html into those.

Comment: @BurakSerdar thanks, didn't know you couldn't do it the django way, will do it that way from now on!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redefine and replace templates like that. Do the reverse: define index.html and blog.html as page1 and page2 respectively, import common header.html and footer.html into those.